# Why can we cover $\mathbb R^N$ with open balls of radius $r$ such that each point is in at most $N + 1$ balls?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, metric-spaces, combinatorial-geometry

> If $N \geq 3$, why can we cover $\mathbb R^N$ with open balls of a fixed radius $r$ such that each point is in at most $N + 1$ balls?

This is a claim in a proof of Lions' Vanishing Lemma, as presented in Willem's *Minimax Theorems* (Lemma 1.21). Probably very simple but I am not able to write a proper proof.

Comment: Open or closed balls?

Comment: Open balls, I have edited to clarify this point

Comment: @PaulFrost Doesn't matter - the two versions of the result are trivially equivalent.

Comment: Intuitively, with closed balls $N$ seems to work also, don't it?

Comment: @DaniloGregorin: No. The centres of $3$ balls are coplanar, so imagine the balls resting on a flat surface. You can rest a fourth ball in the hollow that they form, and there will be a volume immediately below it that is not covered by any of the four. It’s fairly clear intuitively that there is no way to cover that volume without using a ball that intersects all $3$ of the original balls.

Comment: Indeed, I deleted my last comment, it did not make sense. Thank you

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Equivalent - yes. Trivially?

Comment: @PaulFrost Seems trivial to me. Open version implies closed version: $B\subset\overline B$. Closed version implies open version: Let $r>0$. There exists a "good cover" of the form $(\overline B(x_j,r/2))$. So $(B(x_j,r))$ is a good cover by open balls.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Doubling the radius could increase the number of balls intersecting at some points. Even adding a small $\epsilon$ to the radius may not work, if there's no lower bound on the pairwise distances between non-intersecting closed balls.

Comment: @aschepler Oops. That was dumb - thanks...

Comment: Some guy posted on FB (and I agree with him) that this should be a consequence of the existence of a regular simplex grid in $\mathbb{R}^n$... Or are we wrong?

Once you have this regular triangulation, you only need to take balls on the vertices with radius equal to the distance to the center of the regular simplex. For me, it seems the most natural way to face this problem.

Comment: @DCao But regular simplices don't tesselate in $\mathbb{R}^n$ when $n>2$. (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3087543/2236)

Comment: Hmm. We can tessellate $\mathbb{R}^3$ with regular tetrahedra and regular octahedra, and it looks like we can choose $r$ so the balls contain all centers but do not touch any of the opposite faces' planes. And I think that will generalize...

Comment: Let me just point out that if we consider the balls centered at $(rn_1, \ldots, rn_N)$, where $n_i$ is integers, we get that each point is in at most $2^N$ balls, which suffices for the proof of the Lemma

Comment: Nope, my construction fails for $n \geq 5$.

Comment: @DaniloGregorin If the radius is less than $1$, that won't cover $\mathbb{R}^n$ when $n \geq 4$.

Comment: I think this is not known; if such a covering was known to exist for general $N$, then in particular the covering density of the $N$-dimensional ball would be known to be at most $N+1$, but the best upper bound known on the covering density of the ball seems to be $N \log N + N \log \log N + 5N$ due to Rogers (1957) (see e.g. [this chapter](http://www.csun.edu/~ctoth/Handbook/chap2.pdf) in the Handbook of Discrete and Computational Geometry).

Comment: If you haven't already you may want to have a look at the "Lebesgue covering dimension". The wikipedia article mentions some properties, but I have not verified if these properties are enough to prove what you want

Comment: @LouisHainaut: The lebesgue covering dimension has nothing to do with this question, and as user125932 and I have explained, it is most likely still an open problem...

Comment: @aschepler, please, why that won't cover $\mathbb R^N$ if $N \geq 4$?

Comment: @DaniloGregorin: Because the diagonal of the unit hypercube is too long.

Comment: @user21820 but won't it shrink together with the cube, since we are multiplying the coordinates by $r$? (sorry if it is too obvious but I am not seeing it)

Comment: @DaniloGregorin Note $\|(\frac 12, \frac 12, \ldots, \frac 12)\| = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{n}$

Comment: @DaniloGregorin: There is no point to have $r$ when we can trivially assume $r = 1$. My comment was under that assumption. The point is that if you have a unit sphere centred at each vertex of a unit hypercube, they won't cover the centre of that hypercube if its diagonal is too long.

Comment: Thank you both, it is clear now

Comment: Just for completeness: In his original article Lions made only a weaker (and trivial) claim that for each $R$ one can cover ${\mathbb R}^n$ by $R$-balls with multiplicity of the cover $\le$ to some fixed number $m$ independent of $R$. This suffices for the proof. The problem is with Willem's book, who clearly goofed.

Answer (score 5):

*user125932* mentioned in a comment that this seems to be an open problem, since it would imply that the covering density of any $n$-dimensional ball is at most $n+1$. As of 2018, it still seems that nobody can prove a better upper bound on that covering density than $Θ( n · \log n )$; see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0606002) and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.1691). In particular, the first linked paper explicitly states that as $n→∞$, unit balls can cover $\mathbb{R}^n$ with density $\big(\frac12+o(1)\big)\ n\ln n$, as Corollary 2.

Comment: I think that you are answering a different question. If I understood correctly, OP asks about the maximal number of balls at any given point, while your answer treats the question of the average number of balls at a given point, and the latter number is obviously smaller than the former.

Comment: @LouisHainaut: But that inequality is obviously enough to demonstrate that the question is an open problem, which is exactly what I stated in my post. (I said nothing about the maximum depth of the covering.)

Comment: for those that are interested, it is known that a covering exists in which every point is contained in at most $O(n \log n)$ balls -- this was proved by Erdős and Rogers [here](https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1961-04.pdf), refining Rogers' $O(n \log n)$ upper bound on the covering density.

Comment: @user125932: Nice, thanks for your comment!